# Как нарисовать данную фигуру?

Tags: three.js

Как нарисовать данную фигуру (объединить 8 точек кривыми) А после этого закрасить все грани?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужна модель или только картинка?

Comment: Нужен Mesh. Кривые сделать получается (объединить верхние точки с их нижними парами, а вот замкнуть всё это и покрасить грани - нет.

Comment: Я имел ввиду вы хотите дальше эти данные использовать для вывода на экран или для вычислений?

Comment: Только отрисовка.

Comment: И из того, что вы нарисовали не понятно как задается кривая. Это сплайн? Тело вращения? Кривая Безье? Не понятно

Comment: У вас не получается построить триангуляцию?  Точки уже есть?

Comment: Использовал https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/curves/QuadraticBezierCurve3, создавал таким образом 4 кривые, а дальше ничего не выходит. Пытался создать Shape, но как в нем объединить 4 кривые, да ещё и замкнуть их для закрашивания - не ясно. Заранее извиняюсь, опыта в 3D практически никакого. Не понимаю разницу между шейпом, полигоном, поверхностью и т.д.

Comment: Да, все точки есть, включая промежуточные. На выходе 4 кривые по дуге сверху вниз. Нужно замкнуть это всё в фигуру как на прикреплённом изображении и покрасить ее.

Comment: Все понятно. Доберусь до компьютера и попробую вам помочь), а если вы добавите код и часть нашей переписки в вопрос вас и минусовать перестанут

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Обязательно закрою и переоформлю как следует. Откровенно не было времени, прошу прощения.

Answer (score 1):

Если быть точным то это не фигура а тело.

Можно конечно было бы всю триангуляцию сделать вручную, в правильном порядке обойдя вершины и сложив все в буфер, однако в three.js есть специальная абстракция Shape, которая позволяет из плоской фигуры сделать объемную(так называемый extrude);

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как раз для вашего случая, вот

[codepen](https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/XOBxQw)

и сниппет

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(0, 10);
for (var i = 0; i <= Math.PI/2; i += Math.PI/45) 
    shape.lineTo(Math.sin(i)*10, Math.cos(i)*10);
for (var i = Math.PI/2; i >= 0; i -= Math.PI/45) 
    shape.lineTo(Math.sin(i)*8, Math.cos(i)*8);
shape.lineTo(0, 10);

var extrudedGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
  depth: 5, 
  bevelEnabled: false
});

scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(extrudedGeometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()));

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 100, 0x666666, 0x444444)
grid.rotateY(Math.PI/2);
scene.add(grid);

camera.position.set(15,15,15);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/101/three.js"></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'></script>
```

Comment: Еще есть [`.absarc()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/extras/core/Path.absarc) для дуг, так как `THREE.Shape()` наследуется от `THREE.Path()`.